# Escape comma in MySql Statement JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I haven't used MySql for sometime now. Im insert some data into my table. Im trying to insert a *comma seperated* String as the value for my TRAITS column 
*Example :*

"Cuddly , Furry , Lazy"

I would like the commas to be inserted with those words as well however, I keep getting a syntax error : **Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

```
    final int ADMIN_ID = 1;
    final char comma = ',';

    try {

        this.connect_func();

        statement = (Statement) connect.createStatement();

        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ANIMALS (USER_ID , NAME , SPECIES , DOB , PRICE , TRAITS)" +
                                "VALUES" + "('"+ ADMIN_ID +"', 'Bella', 'Dog', '02/12/2019', '"+950.00+"', 'Sweet" + comma +" Hyper " + comma + " Cuddly "+ comma + " obedient')," + 
                                  "('"+ ADMIN_ID +"', 'Coco', 'Cat', '07/15/2016', '"+650.00+"', 'Lazy " + comma + " Cuddly" + comma + "Stubborn');");


        statement.close();


          return true;

    } catch(Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);

        statement.close();

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Learn about prepared statement to prevent sql injection. It also will solve your problem regarding comma escape

Comment: Nfo5o, this is a class project, it's not even gonna get deployed live. But thanks for the very helpful input.

Comment: Also remove single quotes around the price column. It is a numeric value.

Comment: You should always use prepared statements it makes the work with databases easier

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: Remove the semicolon at the end.

Comment: I tested your code, and it actually does not produce an error from the SQL INSERT statement. If you have code with an error, you should post the code that causes the error, not some different code.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) to avoid SQL injection. Do it as follows:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO ANIMALS (USER_ID, NAME, SPECIES, DOB, PRICE, TRAITS) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmt.setString(1, ADMIN_ID);
pstmt.setString(2, "Bella");
pstmt.setString(3, "Dog");
pstmt.setDate(4, java.sql.Date.valueOf("2019-12-02")); // yyyy-mm-dd
pstmt.setDouble(5, 950.0);
pstmt.setString(6, "Cuddly, Furry, Lazy");
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the quotes around the PRICE decimal value
Heres your solution :

```
    final int ADMIN_ID = 1;
    final char comma = ',';

    try {

        this.connect_func();

        statement = (Statement) connect.createStatement();

        statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ANIMALS (USER_ID , NAME , SPECIES , DOB , PRICE , TRAITS)" +
                                "VALUES" + "('"+ ADMIN_ID +"', 'Bella', 'Dog', '02/12/2019', "+950.00+", 'Sweet" + comma +" Hyper " + comma + " Cuddly "+ comma + " obedient')," + 
                                  "('"+ ADMIN_ID +"', 'Coco', 'Cat', '07/15/2016', "+650.00+", 'Lazy " + comma + " Cuddly" + comma + "Stubborn');");


        statement.close();


          return true;

    } catch(Exception e) {

        System.out.println(e);

        statement.close();

        return false;
    }
```